# how to store cart session for logged in user using php

Tags: php, ajax, session, variables, cart

Hello i am creating a simple web app, that users can log in and purchase food stuffs. i have used a tutorial i got online [link to tutorial](http://phppot.com/php/php-shopping-cart-with-jquery-ajax/)

to implement the ordering aspect of this web app, 
now i have implemented a user syatem so that users have to sign in to make an order.

my problem is i noticed that the same cart information is shown to multiple users when logged in, which is wrong. every user should have their own different cart information based on what they might have added up.
so i am asking how can i tie cart information to logged in users or each users.

this is my code snippet

product.php

```
<head>
    <script>
function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('#frmAdd').hide();
    $(editobj).prop('disabled','true');
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'+id+'">'+currentMessage+'</textarea><button name="ok" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')">Save</button><button name="cancel" onClick="cancelEdit(\''+currentMessage+'\','+id+')">Cancel</button>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
}
function cancelEdit(message,id) {
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(message);
    $('#frmAdd').show();
}
function cartAction(action,product_code) {
    var queryString = "";
    if(action != "") {
        switch(action) {
            case "add":
                queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code+'&quantity='+$("#qty_"+product_code).val();
            break;
            case "remove":
                queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code;
            break;
            case "empty":
                queryString = 'action='+action;
            break;
        }    
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajax_action.php",
    data:queryString,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#cart-item").html(data);
        if(action != "") {
            switch(action) {
                case "add":
                    $("#add_"+product_code).hide();
                    $("#added_"+product_code).show();
                break;
                case "remove":
                    $("#add_"+product_code).show();
                    $("#added_"+product_code).hide();
                break;
                case "empty":
                    $(".btnAddAction").show();
                    $(".btnAdded").hide();
                break;
            }    
        }
    },

    error:function (){}
    });

}


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="product-grid">
    <?php
    $product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (!empty($product_array)) { 
        foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
    ?>
        <div class="product-item">
            <form id="frmCart">
<img width="100" src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>">
            <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "MUR".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
            <div><input type="range" name="quantity" id="qty_<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>"  value="1" min="1" max="10">
            <?php
                $in_session = "0";
                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    $session_code_array = array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                    if(in_array($product_array[$key]["code"],$session_code_array)) {
                        $in_session = "1";
                    }
                }
            ?>

            <input data-theme="a" type="button" data-icon="cutlery"  value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction cart-action" onClick = "cartAction('add','<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>');cartAction('add','<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>')"  />

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div><div class="clear-float"></div>
<div id="shopping-cart">


</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    cartAction('','');
})
</script> 





</div>




</div>
</body>
```

and my ajax_action.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

if(!empty($_POST["action"])) {
switch($_POST["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_POST["code"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_POST["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;      
}
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  


<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <img width="50" src="<?php 
                $img = $item["name"];
                $sql = "select * FROM tblproduct where name = '$img'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['image'];
}
?>" /><input type="hidden" name="itemname[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["name"]; ?>"><input type="hidden" name="itemprice[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["price"]; ?>"><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong><br />


                <?php echo "MUR".$item["price"]; ?> x <?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>
                <a style="color:#F30" href="#"  onClick="cartAction('remove','<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>')" class="btnRemoveAction cart-action">Remove Item</a><br /><br />

                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>

<br /><br /><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "MUR".$item_total; ?><input type="hidden" name="amount" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo "N".$item_total; ?>">      
  <?php
}
?>
```

i have tried to change the `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` to something that would always change `$_SESSION["MM_Username"]`, my thinking was that it would probably create the cart variable name based on who was logged in, but that approach didnt seem to go well, 
**can some one please help here**

Comment: How do you know they are the same items and the individuals haven't just added to cart same things? I don't really see how it's possible that different logged in users using their own sessions can have the same cart based on what you have.

Comment: ok, i have tested on my system, localhost

Comment: just imagine you use a system to access a cart , and i also do the same without clearing the cart

Comment: You are logging in with different browsers as two different users?

Comment: what has happnd is that i have put a login over this cart, but the items of the cart are not tied to the present logged in user

Comment: yes two different users, but the same browser, is that a normal behaviour, my thinking is when a new user logs in, he should see only info that partains to him

Comment: if you `print_r($_SESSION);` do you get both user sessions plus the cart?

Comment: If you don't have a proper programming to accommodate same user, same browser logins, different sessions, then you have to change your login to only allow for one user logged in on the same session. You should not allow a current user to have the ability to log in again without being logged out already.

Comment: If you open a new browser, you will simulate two different users and your cart will then be unique to the user.

Comment: yea thanks alot i found a solution to my problem, i appendid a variable to session cart like this cart_item.$mine, so what happens is for every logged in user a new cart session name is created in the id of that user

Comment: Just to clarify, you are allowing a user to be logged in using the same user session with different usernames and separate user data? This is not a typical behavior, you may want to rethink that unless your application requires it.

Comment: $mine = $row_Recordset1['cust_id'];   where  $row_Recordset1['cust_id']; is the user id of the logged in user

Comment: no not the same user session, it cant be the same user session

Comment: Well you said when you `print_r($_SESSION)` you can see two different logged in user logins didn't you?

Comment: so instead of having $_session['cart_item'] i will have $_session['cart_item1'] for a user with id 1

Comment: ohhh am soryy must have made a mistake there

Comment: No, you don't what to have a session that has more than one user logged in on the same session so you shouldn't see: `$_SESSION['user1']; and $_SESSION['user2'];` (or however you have it). Should be like `$_SESSION['username'] == 'myname';` not `$_SESSION['myname'];$_SESSION['yourusername'];` etc...unless you need multiple logins allowed per session.

Comment: ok , i get you, hank you so much let me implement what you have said

Comment: Or you can keep your username set-up however you have it but when the user goes to the login page, it should redirect them somewhere else so they can't log in again.

Comment: On final thing, which is important, you need to fix your sql statements. You are setting yourself up for SQL injection/exploit. You need to bind your parameters,

Comment: Specifically things like `"SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_POST["code"] . "'"` do not do. Someone could send your site a `$_POST` value that will manipulate your sql statement (it could be done simply by using the `cURL` functions. Here is a wikipedia reference on the exploit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: wow thanks alot life saver